# Why does the memory keep growing even though I called free()?

Tags: c, linux, memory, malloc

Here is a simple demo, just `malloc()` and `free()` circularly.

```cpp
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int mallocTime = 100000;
    for (int i=1; i<=mallocTime; i++) {
        int size = (rand()%1024*1024*30);
        char *a = (char*)malloc(size);
        free(a);
    }
    int v; {
        // Pause program.
        scanf("%d", &v);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I noticed that, my memory grows when `mallocTime` gets bigger.
this is the memory status when `mallocTime = 0`

```sh
root     21416  0.0  0.0   6568  1712 pts/4    S+   20:53   0:00 ./a.out
```

While this when `mallocTime = 100000`

```sh
root     21786  0.0  0.5  37328 22204 pts/3    S+   20:55   0:00 ./a.out
```

As you can see, both VSZ and RSS growed.
I wonder why, it's obvious that I correctly freed the memory, why does it still grow? what are the growed memory bytes?

Comment: The OS is Debian10

Comment: `free` generally releases memory for other use within the process; it does not necessarily release it from the process to the operating system.

Comment: your question has nothing in common with memory leaks and linux kernel. Do not use unrelated tags

Answer (score 0):

Most glibc malloc implementations do not return memory to the OS unless:

1. you set the threshold in `mallopt`. But from my experience, the arena is still kept by the system after the releasing memory to the system
2. calling the `malloc_trim` which will release memory to the system https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc_trim.3.html
3. By system call `madvice` https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/madvise.2.html

Do not cast the result of the malloc. If your compiler is complaining it means that you compile the C code using the C++ compiler which is not a very good idea.

Try this:

```
int main(void) {
    size_t mallocTime = 100000;

    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
    while(mallocTime--)
    {
        int size = (rand()%1024*1024*30);
        char *a = malloc(size);
        free(a);
        malloc_trim(0);
    }
    int v; {
        // Pause program.
        scanf("%d", &v);
    }
    return 0;
}
```